# Register page redirects to login page asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I have this site hosted in a couple of places. 
http://web83.jet.studiocoast.com.au/Account/Register

http://flowerpictures.tesselaars.com/Account/Register

Both with the same code.
In a weird way http://flowerpictures.tesselaars.com/Account/Register redirect it to login.

The register action is as simple as

```
//
        // GET: /Account/Register

        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Not sure if this might help but the register view uses
@Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength

What works in one location doesn't in another. Both sit on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're restricting *anonymous* users from accessing this action. This'll happen when you've set the `Authorize` attribute, at the class level - thus cascading accessibility down to your *action methods*.

Remove the `Authorize` attribute that's at the class level, and only add it to applicable *action methods* inside the class.

It'd also be good to look at the `web.config` and check the `Authorize` section where the accessibility is configured for anonymous and authenticated users:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms"/>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <location path="/account/register">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/>    
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If it was at class level no methods should have been able to be accessible.Perhaps the login action is defined in this class. The fact that it works fine at place and not at other is concerning.

Comment: have you checked the web.config on the server that's not playing nice, as detailed in my edit?